# mailitem attachment not shown on the mailitem

Tags: c#, outlook, mailitem

I got problem with programmingly create an outlook mailitem with attachment, 
as following code

```
Outlook.MailItem mail =
                outlook.Application.CreateItem
                (Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
                as Outlook.MailItem; 
 mail.AttachmentAdd.Add(GetTempDir() + "345325.html", Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue,1, Type.Missing);
 mail.Display(true);
```

but when actually open the mailitem, there is no attachment diplayed, even though from the mail size we could identify that attachement has been added

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I got the answer, we have to make sure the mailItem.body is not null and the position is 1.
it works

Comment: OK, let me anwser the this Q, we have to make sure the mail.body is not null, cause the posisition of attechment at least be 1, 0 will be visiable, then if the body is null, the attechment won't been seen